# use layout_column by java coding

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I have a `GridLayout` and inside it some`TextView`. I have used `android:layout_column` in xml and it is working. Now my question is that how can we achieve this through java coding. I have seen some examples but they are like as

```
tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(3));
```

What Should I do for `GridLayout`?

Comment: i'm searching for layout attribute android:layout_count and can't anything in android reference to help you. Is that attribute supported  out of the box in android?

Comment: @weakwire Can you check my answer ? If it can give a direction?

Comment: "how can we achieve this through java coding" . how can you achieve what? i really don't understand. Since i don't know what layout_count does i don't have a reference to your question

Comment: @weakwire You can find it in GridLayout child or more in developer site under GridLayout.LayoutParams........

Comment: there is no reference of android:layout_count there .. or anywhere

Comment: @weakwire I am very very sorry at my foolishness . I had typed it wrong. I am very sorry to waste your valuable time.

Comment: not time wasted. Seems to me you found your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say it is that method but it is substitute and giving what I want .
I have set `TextView` in 4th `column` and 1st `row` by this code.

```
tv.setLayoutParams(new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(0),GridLayout.spec(3)));
```

Waiting if any other answer is available.